# Oracle SQL: "quoted string not properly terminated"

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 11.2 with PHP, and now a strange error occurred while i am trying to insert some informations with a TIMESTAP column.

Here is my PHP method/function to insert a row in the `items` table:

```
public function insert_task($data = [])
{
    return oci_execute(oci_parse($this->conn, "INSERT INTO items (ITEM_AUTHOR_ID, ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_DESCRIPTION, ITEM_TIME_DATE, ITEM_STATUS) 
        VALUES ('".$data['auid']."', '".$data['tasktitle']."', '".$data['taskdescription']."', TO_TIMESTAMP('".$data['taskdate']."', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM'), 0)"));
}
```

To test this above method i uses some dummy data like this, and it works.

```
$this->oracledb->insert_task([
        'tasktitle' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        'taskdescription' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto tempore sit, harum suscipit eum consequuntur.',
        'taskdate' => '01/02/2016 8:00 PM',
        'auid' => '1'
    ]));
```

The above test successfully inserted the data row into the `items` table but a strange error occurred while i try to insert the data using a web form!

Here is a screenshot of that; at the top you can see all the information's received from the web from submission.

[image]

and this error occurs:

> oci_parse(): ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

I have printed the query before it executed to the oracle server, and it seems fine!

> INSERT INTO items (ITEM_AUTHOR_ID, ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_DESCRIPTION, ITEM_TIME_DATE, ITEM_STATUS) 
>               VALUES ('1', 'test therehthehreh', 'Lorem ipsum dolor ... eum consequuntur.', TO_TIMESTAMP('01/02/2016 8:00 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM'), 0)

At first it seems a [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) job but it failed too! Whats wrong here?

Comment: Why were you unable to assign the SQL string to a variable, and then trace it before handing it to Oracle? The problem is that there is a quoted string which is not properly terminated. Look at the string you are giving to Oracle, find the simple and obvious problem that Oracle told you about, and fix it. Don't look at the code that concatenates the string. Look at the actual string that has the problem in it. It's on your computer, not mine. Don't ask me to look at it.

Comment: Not related to your question, but it looks like your code is probably vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks. If you don't know what that means, please please read up on it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett NO its not a issue i think. see the updated answer.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave At first i also thought its a SQL Injection issue, but it seems something else because escaping the string didn't works.

Comment: As I said, I'm not suggesting that the SQL Injection issue is the problem here, but that you (probably) have a serious security issue in your application, if this code is being used. The link I included in my previous comment explains why. On this issue, you need to identify which field is not working, I'd suggest replacing all the variable values with hard-coded strings (`'a'`, for example), then replacing them one-by-one to find the problem.

Comment: Are you saying that you have confirmed that the *exact* string you blockquoted, bit for bit, causes this error?

Comment: What happens if you run that query in sql developer or SQL Plus?

Comment: Let me apologize, i finally figured out that its my mistake because the `ITEM_AUTHOR_ID` is a `NUMBER` but i was passing quoted integer value :/

Comment: That being the case, you should withdraw the question.

Comment: @DanBracuk If Oracle gives you that message for that error, it's arguably worth documenting.

Comment: `oci_parse` generates a `prepared query`. You may be interested in looking at: [oci_bind_by_name — Binds a PHP variable to an Oracle placeholder](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php). All your `sql injection` issue will go away.